# How to refresh table width style of a div after swapping content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, partial-page-refresh

I have two divs. One div contains a table content, the other contains pure text. I switch the contents of two divs. All browsers work fine on the style of the table after swapping except one android browser which completely neglect the style of the table and make td cell width very wide.

```
  <div id="div1_id">Pure Text Content</div> 

  <div id="div2_id>     
         <table width="3000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
            <colgroup>
                <col width="20px" />
                <col width="40px" />  
                 ... 
                <col width="30px" />
                <col width="auto" /> 
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td>row1 col1</td>   
                  <td>row1 col2</td>
                   ...   
                  <td>row1 colx</td>   
                  <td>row1 coly</td>   
              </tr>
              ...
  </div>  
  <script type='text/javascript'> 
        var divOneContent = $('#div1_id').html();
        var divTwoContent = $('#div2_id').html();
        $('#divOneContent').html(divTwoContent);
        $('#divTwoContent').html(divOneContent);
  </script>
```

Is there any jquery method that I can use to refresh the css style of a div after I change the content of the div?  This might help me work around the browser bug for me ?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a .css() method you can use:

```
 $('#div1_id').css(propertyName, value);
```

You can also change the class:

```
 $('#div1_id').attr("class", "newClass");
```

Comment: What about if we have many styles to refresh or we don't even know how many class definitions are inside the div. The issue I encounter is about the td cell width definition defined in <colgroup>.

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divOneContent = $('#div1_id').html();
    var divTwoContent = $('#div2_id').html();
    $('#div1_id').html(divTwoContent);
    $('#div2_id').html(divOneContent);
});
```